# Connecting data in MVC

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I have a Navigation Controller and 2 Views Controllers. The first View Controller is associated with a UIViewController named ViewController. The second is connected to a UIViewController named BookVC. BookVC has a UITextField and is connected via an outlet:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldContent;
```

The connection is made with a button that uses a segue. I want to pass some data between the two and am using the following code which fails:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
BookVC* nextPage = [[BookVC alloc] init];
nextPage = [segue destinationViewController];
nextPage.textFieldContent.text=@"Some content";
}
```

How should I pass data between the View Controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `textFieldContent` doesn't exist at that point.  You'll need to add a property to `BookVC` that can hold the text you want to put into `textFieldContent`... we'll call it `@property NSString *textFieldContentText`.  So then,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    BookVC *nextPage = [segue destinationViewController];
    [nextPage setTextFieldContentText:@"Some content"];
    ...
}
```

And then, in the `-viewDidLoad` method of `BookVC`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [textFieldContent setText:[self textFieldContentText]];
}
```

Comment: I think I'm nearly there. I think the sending file should have:
    BookVC *nextPage = [segue destinationViewController];
    UITextField *tf;
    tf.text = @"Some content";
    [nextPage setTextFieldContent:tf];

However, I don't understand the viewDidLoad statement.
 [nextPage setTextFieldContent:tf];

Comment: The first controller doesn't know about the second controller's text field. It just sets the string that will eventually be placed into the `BookVC`'s `textFieldContent`. `BookVC`'s `-viewDidLoad` method is called automatically when it is loaded. At that point, you know the textFieldContent label exists, and its text can be set, so you do it there. Check out the docs on `UIViewController` and the `-viewDidLoad` method. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ignore the last comment. Your explanation is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line:

```
BookVC* nextPage = [[BookVC alloc] init];
```

That creates a brand new BookVC which you then go and overwrite in the next line.

Since you are using [segue destinationViewController] you should be good to go.  What's happening when you segue to nextPage?